# How to get current month data created at Parse database? Swift Programming Language

Tags: parse-platform, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I have a problem in getting my data in Parse Database that created at this month. I am using swift and Xcode 6.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you can fetch the `createdAt` field as an NSDate.

`myObject["createdAt"] as! NSDate`

There should be plenty of documentation about getting the month out of an NSDate.